# Can't bindService Android()

Tags: android, service

I've been looking at this for a long time now, but I can't fix the Null Pointer Exception being thrown when trying to access `ResolveInfo.serviceInfo` on the null object. (Have to make explicit intent when starting service as of API 20)

Here is the .aidl interface:

```
package com.example.playerclient;

interface AIDLinterface {
    void Play_Clip(int id);
    void Pause_Playback();
    void Resume_Playback();
    void Stop_Player();
}
```

Here is the relevant client code (`onResume()` is where the NPE is thrown)

```
public class PlayerClientMain extends AppCompatActivity
{

    Button button;
    private AIDLinterface mAIDLinterface;
    private boolean mIsBound = false;

    private ServiceConnection mServiceConn = new ServiceConnection()
    {

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder iservice)
        {
            Log.v("SERVICE CONNECTED", "SERVICE CONNECTED");
            mAIDLinterface = AIDLinterface.Stub.asInterface(iservice);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "service connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            mIsBound = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName)
        {
            Log.v("SERVICE DISCONNECTED", "SERVICE DISCONNECTED");
            mAIDLinterface = null;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "service disconnected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mIsBound = false;

        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player_client_main);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();

        if (!mIsBound)
        {
            boolean b = false;
            Intent i = new Intent(AIDLinterface.class.getName());

            ResolveInfo info = getPackageManager().resolveService(i, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE); //this is always null
            i.setComponent(new ComponentName(info.serviceInfo.packageName, info.serviceInfo.name)); //NPE because info is null

            b = bindService(i, this.mServiceConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

            if (b)
                Log.i("SUCCESS:", "bindService() success!");
            else
                Log.i("FAILURE:", "bindService() failed!");
        }
    }
}
```

The service code is not relevant because I cannot reach the bindService() line anyway. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with creating the intent itself.

Assume `AIDLinterface.class` is a service class, you should create the intent like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, AIDLinterface.class);
```

For details, refer https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Cheers~

Comment: AIDLinterface is not the service class. It is the interface that allows a remote service to communicate with my local client (PlayerClient).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this did not help. I no longer get NPE, but bindService() returns false